# Make other children in tablerow fill open space

Tags: flutter, user-interface

I am currently working on a little internal tool to keep track of our roling Release.
I ended up using a table to visualise the timeline and function wise everything is perfect but for some reason I am unable to make the children of the TablerRow fill the available space.

[image: visualisation of the problem]

as you can see here there is a big gap between the container that has text and the other ones. Even though they are in the same TableRow

I tried wrapping the container in expanded Widget, wrapping it with intrinsicHeight, setting hight to double.infity wrapping children of the widget with expanded. But none of it had an effect.

I don't know the height beforehand.
As far as I can tell to the containers there is no "available space" which is probably why none of my attempts worked.

How can I solve this issue?